# How to create Bootstrap Switch with separated "Yes" "No" buttons

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How to create a switch to set a boolean in separated "Yes" "No" buttons?

I work with angular and typescript, so a radio button doesn't work as I need a boolean type.

I mean how to have:

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

In following style:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off" checked>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">YES</label>
  
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">NO</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Instead of trying solve it with CSS, why not just use the value of the _first_ ("Yes")  radio button as your boolean?